# Log in a file only if the database fails?

Tags: nlog

I have a scenario where I want to log in a file only if the database fails for some reason.

Is it possible to achieve that using NLog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use the FallbackGroup target for that. In the fallback group you should configure the database and file target.

e.g.

```xml
<target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="all" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
    <target name="target1" xsi:type="Database" ... />
    <target name="target2" xsi:type="File"     ... />
</target>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="all" />
</rules>
```

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target

Comment: Wow great job ! Thank you :)